# Excel Degree formula based on a right angle tringle

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

I have a formula we use at work to calculate degree for our metal, right now we use a calculator to do this but I feel like if we could just plug the numbers into excel and have it do the hard work for us we could allow more people to do the drawings.

My formula is A divided by B multiplied by INV Yx = degree

A is my rise and B is my width

I can not figure out how to get the INV Yx function that we use on the calculator into excel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to do it after doing some research into other ways to find the degree. Below is the answer using a formula for degree with `ATAN`

```
=DEGREES(ATAN(A/B))
```